# Mocking RestClient ExecuteAsync using Nsubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, restsharp, nsubstitute

Been having a hard time trying to mock out ExecuteAsync method for RestClient (From RestSharp) using Nsubstitute. I have seen an example using Moq (here: [Mocking Restsharp executeasync method using moq](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1389945/Example-for-mocking-RestSharps-IRestClie)) but cannot for the life of me understand why the following code fails using nsubstitute:

```
RestClientMock.When(x => x.ExecuteAsync(Arg.Any<IRestRequest>(), Arg.Any<Action<IRestResponse>>()))
              .Do(x => new RestResponse { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound });
```

That's how I set it up and then it would hit the code to be tested like so:

```
 var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SendEmailResponse>();
_restClient.ExecuteAsync(_restRequest, (restResponse) => {

            if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
               tcs.SetResult(new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.Error, restResponse));

            else if (!_enableEmails)
                tcs.SetResult(new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.EmailsTurnedOff, restResponse));

            else
                tcs.SetResult(new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.Sent, restResponse));

        });

        return tcs.Task;
```

It never seems to execute my callback code in the mock and just hangs as tcs never gets set. Does anybody here have an idea of how to make this work?

EDIT: Resolved. Thanks Nkosi. So I was just newing it up as explained below and not returning. Had I read the documentation more carefully, I'd have seen the section that was mentioned by  David Tchepak in the comments.

Comment: From initial inspection you do not seem to be doing anything with the callback action passed into the mocked method.

Comment: In the `.Do` call you are new'ing up a `RestResponse`, but that is not being used anywhere so it will be ignored. You need to pass that response to the callback, as per @Nkosi's answer. See also: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/, http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From initial inspection you do not seem to be doing anything with the callback action passed into the mocked method

```
RestClientMock
    .ExecuteAsync(
        Arg.Any<IRestRequest>(), 
        Arg.Do<Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle>>(callback => 
            callback(new RestResponse { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound}, null))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The function signature for `ExecuteAsync` is:

```
RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync(IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback);
```

With the sequence of calls:

```
RestClientMock.When(x => x.ExecuteAsync(Arg.Any<IRestRequest>(), Arg.Any<Action<IRestResponse>>()))
              .Do(x => new RestResponse { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound });
```

You are completely overriding the original `ExecuteAsync` function, and it is the implementation of the called function that uses the callback, but your replacement implementation does not use the callback at all!

My suggestion would be to use `ExecuteTaskAsync` instead, in an `async` function:

```
var restResponse = await _restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(_restRequest);
if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    return new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.Error, restResponse);

else if (!_enableEmails)
    return new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.EmailsTurnedOff, restResponse);

else
    return new SendEmailResponse(ResponseType.Sent, restResponse);
```

After that, you should be able to mock the function `ExecuteTaskAsync`.

Comment: The ExecuteAsync that I'm using comes from RestClientExtensions and is defined as : public static RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse> callback);

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible to mock an extension method in Moq?

Comment: It is not possible to mock extension methods with Moq

Comment: You're both right. Extension methods can't be mocked in nsub. I changed the signature to include Restrequestasynchandle and it started hitting the mock but as Nkosi mentioned before, all it did was just new up the response. After reading the doc further and the comments above, I was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Newbie: Given that you want to expose a `Task`-based API, I would suggest using RestClient's Task-based API instead of the callback-based one.

Comment: any ideas on how to mock this method,
 
_restclientMock.When(x => x.ExecuteGetTaskAsync(Arg.Any<IRestRequest>()).Returns(_restResponseMock));

when calling this the content and data is always null regardless of what is set in _restResponseMock which is a substitutefor IRestResponse.

as it seems to be very similar to your answer